# SQLtableDependency doesn't trigger on update triggers only on insertion and deletion of row in dot net core web application

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, signalr, messagebroker

In my dot net core web application, I have subscribed to two tables using SqltableDependency. On one of the table I am able to receive notifications on insert, update and delete. But on other table, update fails to trigger notification.

I checked both the tables, after starting the application, on both the tables triggers are created for insert, update and delete.

I modified the trigger for the table which is not firing notification on update with a print statement, upon updating  a row, I can see the print statement in the  results window in the SQL server.
I tried to drop and recreate the table, but nothing working.